# Leaflet.js polyline color change on mouseover

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a polyLine drawn using a list of points in Leaflet. Here is the code

```
road= new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: color,
    weight: 10,
    lineCap:"square",
    lineJoin:"bevel",
    opacity: 0.6,
    smoothFactor: 1
    });
```

I need to change the color of this polyLine to green on mouseover. I am using the following code. But it's not working.

```
road.on('mouseover', function (e) {
         var layer=e.target;
         layer.options["color"]="green";
         console.log(layer.options["color"]);

        });
```

Can anyone give me any idea how can i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `setStyle` [method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-setstyle), like this:

```
road.on('mouseover', function() {
    this.setStyle({
        color: 'red'   //or whatever style you wish to use;
    });
});
```

Also, to revert to the initial style on `mouseout`, save that style in a variable, and write:

```
road.on('mouseout', function() {
    this.setStyle(initialStyle)
});
```